# How to make a WPF tree view non-collapsible and non-selectable

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

I want to display data from and XML document in a tree-like display but I don't need items to be selectable and I don't want them to be collapsible.

Any way to do this with TreeView?  Is TreeView even the right control to use?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can handle the PreviewMouseDown and cancel the event. If you need to allow scrolling, you can do a HitTest and see if it is over the "ScrollerChrome". If you need more details, I can provide code.

Comment: So far, so good.  Any way to get the little expand/collapse icons to go away?

Comment: You'd have to redefine the TreeViewItem template to do that. I hear Blend would make that easy.